# If the user input == a key of a dictionary then return the value and vice versa. how could I do that?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a program, where in a dictionary, I put in peoples names and their email addresses, and when the user puts in a name it gives back the email. Is their a quicker way to do that other than doing a whole lot of `if` loops or maybe a `for` loop? Any ideas?

Comment: How about `try`?  For example, `try: email = d["Aharon"]`.  `except` can be something like `email = None`.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Just `dictionary[name]` or `dictionary.get(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'Alice': 'alice@mail.com', 'Bob': 'bob@mail.com'}
user_input = input('Input a name:').lower().capitalize()
if user_input in d:
    print(d[user_input])
```

If inputting *Bob*, (irrespective of capitalization), this prints

```
Input a name:Bob
bob@mail.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the reason I didn't do this before is because I was trying to code that the name doesn't have to capitalized. For example, if I put in bob (lowercase) it would still give me the same output. Any ideas on how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: @AharonBecker Just use`.lower().capitalize()`; see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing a whole crazy situation with if conditionals and for loops, but this really works!